HoTT for the working mathematician (especially the homotopy geometer) - what is the current state?
As a starting point for this question, I want to turn to Mike Shulman's paper "All (∞,1)-toposes have strict univalent universes" (2019). Mike shows that

Every $(∞,1)$-topos can be represented by a type-theoretic model topos. This is a model category with a little extra structure and some very nice properties. The main class of examples are directly Bousfield localizations of simplicial presheaves with injective model structure (but this is not trivial, it is one of Mike's theorems). For more details, see Introduction, section 1.3.

Type-theoretic model topos allows interpretation of Book HoTT with univalent universes (without higher inductive types)


I (and many others) find the use of an invariant homotopy-coherent language very convenient and elegant in many real mathematical contexts (especially all those that are somehow related to higher geometry). We can think of it as packaging a powerful model toolkit once and for all inside the language (instead of obscuring the ideas with its technique all the time).
So I wonder how far we can go now in using HoTT as a full-fledged language for writing papers? (I mean such areas as, for example, derived geometry, motives, spectral algebraic geometry of Lurie, analytic geometry of Scholze and Clausen, etc.). Of course, I am interested in any version of HoTT, not necessarily Book HoTT. This could be some version of directed type theory, as in the inspiring project "Synthetic $(∞, 1)$-Category Theory" by Cisinski et al.(see the first materials on nlab and more recent ones on his website)
As far as I know, we do not know at the moment whether any existing version of HoTT is able to reproduce all the interesting mathematics. In the case of Book HoTT, we do not know whether it is possible to define $(∞, 1)$-categories in it. So for the work now we should fix some version of classical discrete foundations (such as ETCS with the axioms of substitution, choice, and Grothendieck universes) as a background. Then we can introduce the Book HoTT notation, just in the sense of the standard interpretation in sSet (as in Shulman's work, but in this case going back directly to Voevodsky). By continuing to appeal to the discrete layer, we can try to effectively extend this notation as needed (see, for example, question 4 below).

Is there anything similar developing in the literature? And are there any papers written in this style? (If there is more than one, then mentioning each would be interesting).

Should we expect any disadvantages in this setting compared to 2-level type theory?  Its possible advantage is that it is easy to provide the reader with a simple and reasoned introduction to the syntax of Martin-Löf type theory / Book HoTT (presenting it directly in the sense of the standard interpretation). Whereas getting to know a new formal language from scratch (such as 2LTT) is unfortunately a significant obstacle for most mathematicians who do not specialize in this field.

What is the current status of interpreting (some class of) higher inductive types in the internal language of $(∞, 1)$-toposes? In Shulman's paper this is stated as an open question. Do we have quotient types? And what is currently known in the case $\mathrm{Type}$ (that is, $\mathrm{sSet_{Quillen}}$) ?

We can try to extend the Book HoTT notation by introducing the notion of $(∞, 1)$-categories (interpreting them as simplicial types satisfying the Segal condition and univalence). If we can show that this definition is equivalent to the standard definition via complete Segal spaces (which would be some kind of ratification statement, if I understand correctly), then we can use all the results of $(∞, 1)$-category theory. And sometimes be able to do things explicitly, in terms of the Book HoTT language. Does this make sense and, if so, is this statement proven somewhere?

Can we, for example, prove basic facts about (homotopy/animated) commutative rings in this way, using HoTT-style reasoning?


The general motive of the question is not tied to the specific questions above. In them I just described one approach that I understand and ask how useful it can be. The general question is about what tools we currently have to formulate and prove as many statements as possible using a HoTT-style language (but of course not necessarily limiting ourselves to the completely homotopy-invariant foundations as I explained above). I would be happy to combine them with the standard model category and infinity-category formalisms whenever convenient. The point is to take advantage of the invariant point of view as much as possible. Any advice and answers in this direction would be appreciated.

Something seems to be even formalized: https://rzk-lang.github.io/sHoTT/ but I hope that some expert could explain this to us.

@Z.M Thanks for that link! But in general, yes, of course, I am familiar with the directed type theory of Riel and Shulman. Can anyone comment on whether it has (currently or potentially) practical advantages over the classical non-invariant approach?

This is a rather broad question, so my answer is necessarily incomplete. However, I can say a few things about $\infty$-category theory in HoTT, I'll leave it others to comment on things like synthetic algebraic geometry or condensed type theory. Also relevant is the work by Cisinski and collaborators which is a bit more distant from book HoTT.
First, the claim that we don't know "whether any existing version of HoTT is able to reproduce all the interesting mathematics" is not entirely true. We know that within HoTT there is a sensible interpretation of ordinary set-level mathematics within suitably truncated types so, for instance, we could define $\infty$-categories as we do in ordinary mathematics with quasi-categories or some other model. Of course, this is hardly satisfying (and we gain very little from doing this in HoTT as opposed to another type theory). The slightly more correct claim is that we don't know how to define various higher structures within HoTT which leverage the built-in homotopical constructs of the type theory.
I have some difficulty understanding what you're proposing in (1)/(2), it seems like you're suggesting that we could extend book HoTT with axioms as needed based on what's validated by the simplicial sets model. This is certainly possible: it's one way of adding/justifying the law of excluded middle, propositional resizing, or any other number of principles to book HoTT. However, if you want to axiomatize something like $\infty$-categories, it's not exactly clear what one would add to the system nor that there will be some finite list of axioms to add which actually capture all the behavior we want. This is sort of the advantage of 2-level type theory: because we have the internal language of simplicial sets available to us, we don't have to worry about predicting what axioms we'll need from the model ahead of time.
As it stands right now, (3) is still open though I believe there is some work in this direction. Note that this issue is basically one of size: we know that various HITs exist in the model but we don't know how to balance the following two constraints: strict computation rules and HITs built from $\mathcal{U}_i$-small parameters are themselves $\mathcal{U}_i$-small. If you drop the first, one can justify this using e.g., the presentability of the underlying $\infty$-categories and if you drop the second, you can construct the HITs in the model categories using the approach of Lumsdaine-Shulman'19.
For (4)/(5) the story is slightly more positive. This is the domain of simplicial type theory which axiomatizes some aspects of simplicial spaces to realize $\infty$-categories as complete Segal spaces. You mentioned you're familiar with rzk, so I'll just mention that the original work in this direction is Riehl-Shulman (this contains the specific adequacy result you asked about) and that there has been follow up work by Licata-Weaver, Martínez, and several papers by Ulrik Buchholtz and Jonathan Weinberger.
The most recent paper by those two (and myself, sorry for the self promotion) does give a type-theoretical construction of the $\infty$-category of spaces along with enough machinery to at least define animated commutative rings. I'm working with a student right now exploring some of the basic results of animation in this setting. Some stuff is very straightforward and pleasant, but we don't have the theory of presentable categories available yet so a lot of results need to wait until that is better developed. If you're happy to just add axioms for facts from standard $\infty$-category theory then this step can be skipped.
As to the question about whether this is all ready for mathematicians to use to write papers which are not about synthetic $\infty$-category theory, I think it's probably too early to tell. The main obstructions are that (1) one needs modal homotopy type theory, which is rather complicated and (2) we're still reproducing pretty basic results from e.g., HTT right now in simplicial type theory. However, we're gradually working to resolve (2) and the state of modal type theory has improved considerably over the last 15 years, so I'm cautiously optimistic.

You mention animated commutative rings. I guess that it extends to all Lawvere theories?

Does that also extend to derived commutative rings (due to Bhatt–Mathew, extending ideas of Brantner–Mathew and Illusie's right-left extensions, see Raksit's paper on Hochschild homology).

@Z.M I expect our methods scale to arbitrary lawvere theories, but that's still on our todo list. I'm not familiar with derived commutative rings, but glancing through Raksit's paper these look a bit more distant, but this is just an impression at a glance :)

Arpon did it in the generality of "derived algebraic contexts", but the basic idea is that the monad $\operatorname{LSym}\colon D_{\ge0}(\mathbb Z)\to D_{\ge0}(\mathbb Z)$ extends to the whole derived category, since the monad in question is close to be polynomial.

Thank you very much for this amazing answer! Regarding 3: does the alternative have interesting implications in practice (in the sense of the question)? We can't directly interpret the book HoTT with higher inductive types in infinity-topos, but we can.. (something?)?

I know about simplicial type theory and that it was created by Riehl and Shulman, but I haven't looked closely at their work directly. Thanks for the reference. Wow, your and co-authors' paper on triangulated type theory is very exciting! I look forward to seeing how your ideas develop!
